# How to load data into Combobox?

Tags: extjs

I try to fill the form with the response data from the backend,but my formpanel contains combobox,how could load the data into combobox.

I tried to use the method setValues() in formpanel,and I set the displayField and valueField, but the combobox still shows **[object,object]**.

### Here is my store code

```
Ext.define('Servicemsg.directory.AppSystemStore', {
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    fields:['id','code','name','comments','lastupdatetime'],
    proxy:{
        type:'ajax',
        url:'',
        reader:{
            type:'json',
        }
    },
})
```

### Here is the code of combobox

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    label: 'Provider',
    name:'provider',
    store:Ext.create('Servicemsg.directory.AppSystemStore'),
    displayField:'name',
    valueField:'id',
    autoLoadOnValue:true
  }
```

### Here is my request code

```
form.load({
                url:'#url#'+data.id,
                success:function (form,result,data) {
                    form.setValues(result.result);
                }
            });
```

### Response data like this

```
{
name:'',
text:'',
id:'',
provider:{
   id:'',
   name:'',
  }
}
```

Comment: You didnt load data in AppSystemStore since its bind to combo. Can you put some small version of runnable code in fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the combobox of the form and add the values to the combobox's store manually. Once the combobox store has the values, you can set a value to the combobox if applicable.

```
form.load({
    url:'#url#'+data.id,
         success:function (form,result,data) {
                const combobox = form.down('combobox');
                combobox.getStore().add(results.providers);
                combobox.setValue(/*value that the comobobox should show*/);
                form.setValues(result.result);
            }
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in this case using a store is overkill. Considering you have an 
empty proxy and are just using it to try and load data into your combobox.

Instead you should create a View Model and with a property `comboBoxData`. You should
then bind this value to the `data` property on your combox box.

This is what your model would like like

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.view.main.MainModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    data: {
        comboBoxData: null
    }
});
```

This is what your combo box should look like

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    label: 'Provider',
    name: 'provider',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id',
    autoLoadOnValue: true,
    bind: {
        data: '{comboBoxData}'
    }
}
```

This is what your success function would look like. 
(How you get the view model will depend on where this is being called)

```
success: function (form, result, data) {
    var vm = this.lookupViewModel();
    vm.set('comboBoxData', result.result);
}
```

You may have to tweak this for you specific implementation. But, hopefully this gives you a good idea of the best approach for this.